# Convert UTF-8 character sequence to real UTF-8 bytes

Tags: encoding, utf-8, iconv

I have a plain text-file (.yml) that contains UTF-8 character sequences like this:

foo: "Dette er en \xC3\xB8 "

The problem lies in \xC3\xB8 - These are not "real" UTF-8 bytes, since they are saved in the text file as 8 actual characters: \ x C 3 \ x B 8

Is there a way to get these converted into the real 2-bytes UTF-8 sequence?

Any OS / Language / Shell-tool may be used :-)

/ Carsten

Comment: is there only this 'sequence'?

Comment: No this is just an example. There are all kinds of non-ascii characters from a lot of different languages. So a simple regexp replacement is out of the question.

Comment: May the text contain such escaped sequences by 'intention' (that the author really typed in)?

Comment: I think it is simply a case of some UTF-8 files being opened in a non-utf8 editor and saved as ISO-8859-1 instead. Or something like that. Quite a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this perl script to convert your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<STDIN>) {
  $_ =~ s/\\x([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])/chr(hex($1))/eg;
  print $_;
}
```

Let's assume you named a file with script as `bogusutf`, then do the conversion with this command:

> $ perl bogusutf *<inputfile >outputfile*

Comment: This is where Perl truly shines.

Comment: Just what I needed - my Perl is a bit rusty. Thanks!