# Printing a string containing utf-8 byte sequences on perl

Tags: linux, perl, unicode, utf-8, mork

I'm new to perl, and I'm trying to print out the folderName from mork files (from Thunderbird).

From: https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/mork-converter/blob/master/doc/mork-format.txt

> The second type of special character sequence is a dollar sign
>   followed by two hexadecimal digits which give the value of the
>   replacement byte. This is often used for bytes that are non-printable
>   as ASCII characters, especially in UTF-16 text. For example, a string
>   with the Unicode snowman character (U+2603):
>
> ☃snowman☃
>
> may be represented as UTF-16 text in an Alias this way:
>
> <(83=$03$26s$00n$00o$00w$00m$00a$00n$00$03$26)>

From all the Thunderbird files I've seen it's actually encoded in UTF-8 (2 to 4 bytes).

The following characters need to be escaped (with `\`) within the string to be used literally: `$`, `)` and `\`

Example: `aaa\$AA$C3$B1b$E2$98$BA$C3$AD\\x08` should print `aaa$AAñb☺í\x08`

`$C3$B1` is `ñ`; `$E2$98$BA` is `☺`; `$C3$AD`is `í`

I tried using the regex to replaced unescaped `$` into `\x`

```
my $unescaped = qr/(?<!\\)(?:(\\\\)*)/;
$folder =~ s/$unescaped\$/\\x/g;
$folder =~ s/\\([\\$)])/$1/g;   # unescape "\ $ ("
```

Within perl it just prints the literal string.

My workaround is feeding it into bash's printf and it succeeds... unless there's a literal "\x" in the string

```
$ folder=$(printf "$(mork.pl 8777646a.msf)")
$ echo "$folder"
  aaa$AAñb☺í
```

Questions i consulted:

[Convert UTF-8 character sequence to real UTF-8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668670/convert-utf-8-character-sequence-to-real-utf-8-bytes)
But it seems it interprets every byte by itself, not in groups.

[In Perl, how can I convert an array of bytes to a Unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788262/in-perl-how-can-i-convert-an-array-of-bytes-to-a-unicode-string)
I don't know how to apply this solution to my use case.

Is there any way to achieve this in perl?

Comment: See also [Evaluating escape sequences in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8740106/2173773)

Comment: See also [String::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Escape)

Comment: If you omitted the last unescape substitution, you could simply have used `eval "\"$folder\""`.. But using `eval` is in general not safe, so better to use e.g. `String::Escape`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following substitution seems to work for your input:

```
s/\\([\$\\])|\$(..)/$2 ? chr hex $2 : $1/ge;
```

Capture `\$` or `\\`, if matched, replace them with `$` or `\`. Otherwise, capture `$..` and convert to the corresponding byte.

If you want to work with the result in Perl, don't forget to decode it from UTF-8.

```
$chars = decode('UTF-8', $bytes);
```

Comment: choroba uses `/r` causes the modified string to be returned rather than modifying the string in-place. Just remove the `r` is you want to continue working in-place.

Comment: Without knowing the spec, `\\(\W)` is probably better than `\\([\$\\])`. `s{\\(\W)|\\(\w))|\$([0-9a-fA-F]{2})|\$}{ defined($1) ? $1 : defined($2) ? die("Unsupported \\$2 escape") : defined($3) ? chr(hex($3)) : die('Invalid "$" sequence') }ges`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is using Encode::decode necessary if I just want to print out the result? (to capture it into a bash variable). From what I experimented if I use it, it complains about printing a wide character, unless i set `binmode (STDOUT, ":utf8");`

Comment: @Bangaio Yes, you need to encode all output to a terminal that will contain non-ascii characters. You can do this by either leaving it encoded (if you are sure it is already in the encoding your terminal expects and you don't want to do any string operations first), explicitly encoding the decoded string with Encode::encode, or setting an encoding layer like you mentioned so all strings are encoded when sent to that handle (but you should use `:encoding(UTF-8)`, not `:utf8`). The only problem with the last option is that it is a global effect, other things might not expect it.